# How to use QueryPerformanceCounter to get results in seconds?

Tags: c++, windows, timer, type-conversion

```
BOOL QueryPerformanceCounter(
__out LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount
);

LARGE_IN
TEGER startTimer()
{
LARGE_INTEGER start;
DWORD_PTR oldmask = SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 0);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), oldmask);
return
start;
}

LARGE_INTEGER endTimer()
{
LARGE_INTE
GER stop;
DWORD_PTR oldmask = SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 0);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), oldmask);
return
stop;
}
```

I'm using those functions but I'm not sure in what type it returns values.
endTimer - startTimer = ?  How to convert this result to get seconds ?

Comment: MSDN has all the info, did you try to read it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get frequency and divide your 2 counters difference by it.

```
LARGE_INTEGER fr,t1,t2;

QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

// some lengthy code ...

QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&fr);

double diff_sec = (t2.QuadPart-t1.QuadPart)/(double)fr.QuadPart;
```